# Plasma concentration multiple doses Equations in js

Tags: javascript, equation-solving

Currently my app needs to calculate the plasma concentration (multiple doses). I'm expecting it to be cyclical like depicted in this case: [image: Wikipedia example]

However, when I try to calculate and plot it out, it comes out like [image: current graphed plot]

The equation that I was told that it should be is [image: relavent pharmacokentic equation]
and my function looks like the one below

```
function calculatePlasmaConcentration(x, bioavailability, vd, ka, ke, dosing, dose) {
    var firstPart, secondPart, c;

    firstPart = ((bioavailability * dose * ka) / (vd * ka - vd * ke));
    secondPart = (Math.exp(-ke * x) / (1 - Math.exp(-ke * dosing))) - (Math.exp(-ka * x) / (1 - Math.exp(-ka * dosing)));
c = firstPart * secondPart;

    return c;
}
```

I can't seem to see that I wrote the equation wrong, what am I doing wrong? the parameter x should be time in hours.

adding the default values here:

```
defaultDrugInfo = {
    dose: 500,
    dosing: 24,
    bioavailability: .89,
    ka: .883,
    ke: .0578,
    vd: 6,
    optimalTopRange: 10,
    optimalBottomRange: 5
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can print out those two parts and find out what's wrong

Comment: Could you provide the variables `ke`, `dosing` and `dose`?

Comment: @chocolateentities well the problem is that i didn't make the first graph so i have no idea of the points at every step. and its not that the equation is wrong per se... just wondering why it's not cyclical like the first graph.

Comment: @Daemedeor - So, you want to compute plasma concentration for 0 - 104 hours?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py well at least long enough to see some cyclical pattern like the first graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function `calculatePlasmaConcentration(...)` this way:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/cphske3r/)

```
// four cycles
for (cycle = 0; cycle < 4; cycle++) {
    // 24 hr dosing
    for (t = 0; t < 24; t++) {
        nums.push(Math.round(calculatePlasmaConcentration(t, 0.89, 6, 0.883, 0.0578, 24, 500) * 1000) / 1000);
    }
}
```

The graph created by the numbers generated by this function is:

[image]

### [Edit]

When the time hits 24 hour intervals, the plasma concentration values for the next day are supposed to add up with the last plasma concentration value from the previous day, since the dose doesn't just disappear from the body.

Next, when we append the `tau(τ)`, (`i` in our case) along with the plasma concentration value(`temp.push([i + delta, pcStack + pc]);`) we need to add up `24` to `i`, everytime the time hits 24 hour intervals.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/cphske3r/8/)

This is the updated function.

```
function generateData(drugInfo) {
    var pcStack = 0;
    var temp = [],
        mainArray = [],
        tempObject = {};
    var start = 0;
    var end = 24;
    var delta = 0;
    for (cycle = 0; cycle < 4; cycle++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 24; i += 0.05) {
            var pc = calculatePlasmaConcentration(i, drugInfo.bioavailability, drugInfo.vd, drugInfo.ka, drugInfo.ke, drugInfo.dosing, drugInfo.dosage);
            temp.push([i + delta, pcStack + pc]);
        }
        pcStack += pc;
        delta += 24;
    }
    tempObject = {
        data: temp
    };
    mainArray.push(tempObject);
    return mainArray;
}
```

Comment: hmmm interesting,, I think that the use of cycles is missing though? Cause when I tried it out, it just resolved back to the beginning. I'll see what I can do to fix it on my end. and then i'll mark it correct... cause i'm using flot's library to render the grpah so 

this is how i'm calling it right now: 'for (var i = 0; i < length; i += steps) { temp.push([i, func(i, drugInfo.bioavailability, drugInfo.vd, drugInfo.ka, drugInfo.ke, drugInfo.dosing, drugInfo.dosage)]);}'

Comment: @Daemedeor - Please add the entire code to your question or create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: fair enough, one moment.

Comment: Here you go an updated fiddle of what my thing is plotting without your updates: http://jsfiddle.net/cphske3r/1/

Comment: @Daemedeor - It's done! Check out the updated answer.

Comment: oh @chipChocolate.py one note, isn't the pcStack supposed to equal the last pc so you're not "+=" instead you're just setting it at the last opertunity

Comment: If you replace `+=` with `=`, it will just add it once.

Comment: @Daemedeor - [Have a look at this](http://www.pharmpress.com/files/docs/clinical_pharmacokinetics_samplechapter.pdf#page=24&zoom=auto,-186,663).